# Передача значений

Tags: php, javascript

Есть ссылки на удаление записей из БД, точнее говоря, на открытие модального окна, где подтверждается удаление:

```
{foreach from=$getArticle item=article}
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteArticle">remove</a>{/foreach}
```

Само модальное окно выглядит так:

```
<div class="modal" id="deleteArticle">
<input type="button" class="button button-bg-red" onClick="location.href='/index.php?act=all&delete={$page.id}'" value="УДАЛИТЬ" name="">
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что в `{$page.id}` попадает последний id записи из запроса, соответственно удаляется не та запись, которая нужна. Нужно как-то передать из первой ссылки, номер `{$page.id}` в модальное окно, вот только как грамотно это реализовать?

Comment: @xenon, добавили бы код, который создает у Вас модальное окно и показывает его. Было бы проще. А так могу предложить добавить аттрибут `data-id="{$id}"`, а потом значение аттрибута использовать в модальном окне(Когда срабатывает event).

Comment: @xenon, может, Вы мне всё-таки писали? А не товарищу @IamS? Если всё-таки мне: Не будьте так уверены, "в JS нет никакой встроенной функции" -  http://jsfiddle.net/4quoqbus/

Comment: @stck, спасибо, Ваш комментарий изначально не видел. Попробую сделать, как Вы написали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток. Данную операцию я бы осуществил вот таким образом:

Все ссылки выводил бы через **php**:

```
<?php
$i = 1
while($i < $countColumn){
  echo "<a href='$i'>Удалить запись ID$i</a>";
  $i++;
}
?>
```

То бишь `$i` - наш счетчик, а `$countColumn`  - это Ваше значение столбиков в таблице, его считаете через запрос к **MySQL**.

А потом через **jQuery** выводим модальное окно:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Скрываем наше окно, кстати, сам див оставляем пустым,
  $('#deleteArticle').hide();

  //Создаем функцию клика по ссылке 
  $('a').click(function(){

    //Генерируем ссылку
    var link = '/index.php?act=all&delete='+$(this).attr('href');

    //Теперь заносим в наш див кнопочку, именно поэтому мы его оставляем прежде пустым
    $('#deleteArticle').html('<input type="button" class="button button-bg-red"        onClick="location.href='+link+'" value="УДАЛИТЬ" name="">');

    //И теперь его показываем
    $('#deleteArticle').show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Как-то так, в общем.

Comment: А как-то по простому можно без использования jQuery?)

Comment: @xenon, чистый javasctipt, будет чуток запарнее), но если хотите, то могу написать

Comment: @IamS, а в JS нет никакой встроенной функции, чтоб получить информацию из атрибута id, к примеру. Просто тогда я бы сделал ссылку, например, такую `<a href="#deletePage" id="20">Удалить</a>`, и число 20 передал бы как-нибудь в окно)

Comment: @xenon, вот так делаете:

`<a href="#deletePage" onclick='link(20)'>Удалить</a>
function link(id){
  //Тут уже творите чудеса
}`